# Is there a way to improve the entity autoselect especially for multiple entities?

Tags: forms, 9

The entity autoselect is a strange UI element that lets you type something, if you select a match, it puts that text in. If you want to include two items you need `,`  to separate them.

- What if there are commas in the title of the selected entities?
- It's very easy for the user to hit backspace (or similar) and leave the entity improperly specified.
- Expanding on the last point, if a selected entity is `Something (123)` then hitting backspace to `Something (12` will no longer match the entity; you'd then have to backspace some more back to just `Something`, wait, then click the entity again.

I can't be the only one thinking this UX could be improved, but I haven't found a [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_module) yet. Even something as venerable as a jQuery Select2 type selector would be an improvement.

Comment: The reason why you get `Something (123)` is because you can have entities with the same title.  So if you had `Something (123)` and `Something (124)` and you didn't show the ID, there would be no way to tell which `Something` is `Something`.

Comment: I use the Entity Browser module (http://dgo.to/entity_browser). It takes a bit to learn how it works, but it is a supremely better UI than the autocomplete.

Comment: @PatrickKenny I understand why the nid is added, it just makes no UX sense to have that part of the editable text.